# THREE.js updating object matrix after setting position with Raycaster

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a run into a problem with FPS camera controls in a three.js scene. I'm using a `Raycaster` to determine the camera group position based on it's intersection with the scene along the Y axis (a poor man's gravity if you will =) and then apply user input to move around. The camera group position keeps getting reset to the intersection location on every frame, essentially gluing you to the spot.

I'm assuming this is either an `updateMatrix()` problem or a that a `Vector3` is getting passed by reference somewhere, but for the life of me I can't seem to put my finger on it. I need some help... I hope this code is clear enough to help understand the problem :

```
renderer.setAnimationLoop((event) => {

    if (clock.running) {

        update();

        renderer.render(scene,character.view);

    }

});

clock.start();


// 


const update = () => {


   // velocity


   const velocity = new THREE.Vector3();

   velocity.x = input.controller.direction.x;
   velocity.z = input.controller.direction.y;

   velocity.clampLength(0,1);

   if (velocity.z < 0) {

      velocity.z *= 1.4;

   }


   // gravity


   if (scene.gravity.length() > 0) {

      const origin = new THREE.Vector3().copy(character.view.position);
      const direction = new THREE.Vector3().copy(scene.gravity).normalize();

      const intersection = new THREE.Raycaster(origin,direction).intersectObjects(scene.collision).shift();

      if (intersection) {

         character.group.position.copy(intersection.point);

         character.group.updateMatrix();

      }

   }


   // rotation


   const rotation = new THREE.Euler();

   rotation.x = input.controller.rotation.y;
   rotation.y = input.controller.rotation.x;

   character.group.rotation.set(0,rotation.y,0);
   character.view.rotation.set(rotation.x,0,0);


   // velocity.applyEuler(rotation);


   const quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();

   character.group.getWorldQuaternion(quaternion);

   velocity.applyQuaternion(quaternion);


   // collision


   const origin = new THREE.Vector3().setFromMatrixPosition(character.view.matrixWorld);
   const direction = new THREE.Vector3().copy(velocity).normalize();

   const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(origin,direction);

   for (const intersection of raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.collision)) {

      if (intersection.distance < 0.5) {


         // face normals ignore object quaternions


         const normal = new THREE.Vector3().copy(intersection.face.normal);
         const matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().extractRotation(intersection.object.matrixWorld);

         normal.applyMatrix4(matrix);


         // normal


         normal.multiplyScalar(velocity.clone().dot(normal));

         velocity.sub(normal);

      }

   }


   // step


   const delta = 0.001 / clock.getDelta();

   velocity.multiplyScalar(delta);


   // apply


   character.group.position.add(velocity);

}
```

The camera setup is a lot like the PointerLockControls helper, the camera being a child of a Group Object for yaw and pitch. The controller input is defined elsewhere as it can come from the mouse or a gamepad, but it returns normalized values.

To be more precise, the part that is causing the problem is here :

```
   // gravity


   if (scene.gravity.length() > 0) {

      const origin = new THREE.Vector3().copy(character.view.position);
      const direction = new THREE.Vector3().copy(scene.gravity).normalize();

      const intersection = new THREE.Raycaster(origin,direction).intersectObjects(scene.collision).shift();

      if (intersection) {

         character.group.position.copy(intersection.point);

         character.group.updateMatrix();

      }

   }
```

if I comment out `character.group.position.copy(intersection.point);`, for example, the camera moves like it's supposed to (except of course it's flying), but otherwise it moves a frame's worth of distance and then gets reset back to the intersection point on the next frame.

I have tried all manner of updateMatrix(), updateMatrixWorld(), updateProjectionMatrix(), and Object.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true, but alas no joy.

I apologise for using a copy/paste of my code rather than a testable case scenario. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Holy cow, I feel dumb... `const origin = new THREE.Vector3().copy(character.view.position);` returns local space coordinates, of course it gets reset to the origin!

replacing it with `const origin = new THREE.Vector3().setFromMatrixPosition(character.view.matrixWorld);` gives me the proper result

There's a lesson in there somewhere about staring blankly et your code for too long. I hope at least that this question helps someone out there one day.